# Is it possible to start ARC app minimized

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I would like to start my ARC app minimized or hidden if possible. For chrome apps I can use the CreateWindowOptions in the method chrome.app.window.create https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-CreateWindowOptions

Is there some metadata tag available?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. There is no such metadata tag currently.

Feel free to file a [bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG) to request such a feature.